# Reference request concerning the generalized Jacobian Conjecture

Tags: reference-request, jacobian-conjecture

On [page 287](http://www.seminariomatematico.unito.it/rendiconti/cartaceo/55-4/283.pdf), A. van den Essen says:

> Furthermore one can show that it suffices to prove JC for all $n \geq 2$ and for all $F$'s of the form:
>   $F=(l_1,\ldots,l_r,x_{r+1}+M_{r+1},\ldots,x_n+M_n)$ where each $l_i$ is linear and each $M_j$ is a monomial.

Please, where a proof of this result can be found? (I remember I have once found an article with this result, but not I am not able to find it again).

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to ask Van den Essen?

Comment: Probably. But I preferred to ask here before asking van den Essen. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: A related paper is the following: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404903002561 (but it is not exactly what I was looking for).